# How to find where crickets are entering?

Tags: basement

We occasionally find crickets in our mostly unfinished basement.  We don't often open the windows down there and we haven't noticed any unusual drafts.  We don't have any dryer vents there.  There are two openings for outside faucets, but they're well sealed.  We do have a sump-pump but that's also sealed.

We don't really have a problem with any other insects or rodents.  Just crickets (so far).

How do I find where they're entering?  Is this a DIY worthy fix, or should I hire a pro?

(I have never dealt with crickets before in any capacity; they are unfamiliar to me)

Comment: Good Luck, they can fit through a 1/8" crack anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I have wondered the same for our bedroom. I found they are actually able to come through the very tiny space between the balcony door and floor (it's sliding door). I would suggest that you search for tiny crack by the window or vent.

Comment: Thanks; how did you discover that?

Comment: @jglouie by accident really. I saw one coming through while the door was closed.